# Python print hyperlinked text to Spyder Console

Tags: python, spyder

I'm using the WinPython distribution on Windows 7, which comes with the Spyder IDE (and I hope this will work the same on Anaconda).  I would like to know how to print hyperlinked text to the console output.

I assume it's possible, because when I get an error in my code, I get the traceback that shows me where it crashed, and those links are clickable, and will then open the line of the function where it raised the error.  See below:

(I can't post the image without 10 rep, that's lame, I'm new to the site)  See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ3Aw.png

However, I don't want to just open a file within the IDE, what I want to do is have a link to the folder location where my code just saved some plot images to disk, and when I click on the link, have it open the folder within windows explorer.  Bonus points if there is a platform independent way of doing this, but a windows only solution would be sufficient for me.

I have some previously existing Matlab code that would do this for me, but I can't determine if there is a Python equivalent:

```
save_path = pwd;
fprintf('Plots saved to: <a href="matlab: web(''%s'',''-browser'');">%s</a>\n',save_path,save_path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been deprecated.

I find a reference here:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7499#issue-36016539